# Run Multiple Athena Queries in Airflow 2.0

Tags: python, airflow, boto3, amazon-athena

I am trying to create a DAG in which one of the task does `athena` query using `boto3`. It worked for one query however I am facing issues when I try to run multiple athena queries.

This problem can be broken as follows:-

1. If one goes through [this](https://www.ilkkapeltola.fi/2018/04/simple-way-to-query-amazon-athena-in.html) blog, it can be seen that `athena` uses `start_query_execution` to trigger query and `get_query_execution` for getting `status`, `queryExecutionId` and other data about the query (docs for [athena](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html))

After following the above pattern I have following code:-

```
import json
import time
import asyncio
import boto3
import logging
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator


def execute_query(client, query, database, output_location):
    response = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=query,
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': database
        },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': output_location
        }
    )

    return response['QueryExecutionId']


async def get_ids(client_athena, query, database, output_location):
    query_responses = []
    for i in range(5):
        query_responses.append(execute_query(client_athena, query, database, output_location))    

    res = await asyncio.gather(*query_responses, return_exceptions=True)

    return res

def run_athena_query(query, database, output_location, region_name, **context):
    BOTO_SESSION = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id = 'YOUR_KEY',
        aws_secret_access_key = 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY')
    client_athena = BOTO_SESSION.client('athena', region_name=region_name)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    query_execution_ids = loop.run_until_complete(get_ids(client_athena, query, database, output_location))
    loop.close()

    repetitions = 900
    error_messages = []
    s3_uris = []

    while repetitions > 0 and len(query_execution_ids) > 0:
        repetitions = repetitions - 1
        
        query_response_list = client_athena.batch_get_query_execution(
            QueryExecutionIds=query_execution_ids)['QueryExecutions']
      
        for query_response in query_response_list:
            if 'QueryExecution' in query_response and \
                    'Status' in query_response['QueryExecution'] and \
                    'State' in query_response['QueryExecution']['Status']:
                state = query_response['QueryExecution']['Status']['State']

                if state in ['FAILED', 'CANCELLED']:
                    error_reason = query_response['QueryExecution']['Status']['StateChangeReason']
                    error_message = 'Final state of Athena job is {}, query_execution_id is {}. Error: {}'.format(
                            state, query_execution_id, error_message
                        )
                    error_messages.append(error_message)
                    query_execution_ids.remove(query_response['QueryExecutionId'])
                
                elif state == 'SUCCEEDED':
                    result_location = query_response['QueryExecution']['ResultConfiguration']['OutputLocation']
                    s3_uris.append(result_location)
                    query_execution_ids.remove(query_response['QueryExecutionId'])
                 
                    
        time.sleep(2)
    
    logging.exception(error_messages)
    return s3_uris


DEFAULT_ARGS = {
    'owner': 'ubuntu',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'start_date': datetime(2021, 6, 8),
    'retries': 0,
    'concurrency': 2
}

with DAG('resync_job_dag', default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS, schedule_interval=None) as dag:

    ATHENA_QUERY = PythonOperator(
        task_id='athena_query',
        python_callable=run_athena_query,
        provide_context=True,
        op_kwargs={
            'query': 'SELECT request_timestamp FROM "sampledb"."elb_logs" limit 10;', # query provide in athena tutorial
            'database':'sampledb',
            'output_location':'YOUR_BUCKET',
            'region_name':'YOUR_REGION'
        }
    )

    ATHENA_QUERY
```

On running above code, I am getting following error:-

```
[2021-06-16 20:34:52,981] {taskinstance.py:1455} ERROR - An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1112, in _run_raw_task
    self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1285, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1315, in _execute_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 117, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 128, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/iac-airflow/dags/helper/tasks.py", line 93, in run_athena_query
    query_execution_ids = loop.run_until_complete(get_ids(client_athena, query, database, output_location))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 484, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/ubuntu/iac-airflow/dags/helper/tasks.py", line 79, in get_ids
    res = await asyncio.gather(*query_responses, return_exceptions=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 602, in gather
    fut = ensure_future(arg, loop=loop)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 526, in ensure_future
    raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is '
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
```

I am unable to get where I am going wrong. Would appreciate some hint over the issue

Comment: Why don't you just use multiple AWSAthenaOperator?

Comment: Yep, I think I complicated the issue a bit with asyncio. I tried using multiple operator and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are doing here isn't really needed.
Your issues ares:

1. Executing multiple queries in parallel.
2. Being able to recover `queryExecutionId` per query.

Both issues are solved simply by using `AWSAthenaOperator`. The operator already handles everything you mentioned for you.

Example:

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.athena import AWSAthenaOperator


with DAG(
    dag_id="athena",
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    catchup=False,
) as dag:

    start_op = DummyOperator(task_id="start_task")
    query_list = ["SELECT 1;", "SELECT 2;" "SELECT 3;"]

    for i, sql in enumerate(query_list):
        run_query = AWSAthenaOperator(
            task_id=f'run_query_{i}',
            query=sql,
            output_location='s3://my-bucket/my-path/',
            database='my_database'
        )
        start_op >> query_op
```

Athena tasks will be created dynamically simply by adding more queries to `query_list`:

[image]

Note that the `QueryExecutionId` is [pushed to xcom](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/6236e7e205f3dcff3b1f003b7897ba3f549454be/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/athena.py#L123) thus you can access the in a downstream task if needed.

Comment: Does this for loop work correctly inside DAG? I get error: Broken DAG. My dag:

read_date_information_file = PythonOperator(
        task_id="read_date_information_file",
        python_callable=get_date_information
    )

    for i, event in enumerate(read_date_information_file.output):
        test = PythonOperator(
            task_id=f"test_{i}",
            python_callable=test_fn,
            op_kwargs={'event': event}
        )

Comment: @seou1 if you copy the code you will see it's working. Your loop is different. You can open a question with your code and traceback

Comment: here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69289098/airflow-executing-a-step-multiple-times

Comment: Basically i also need AWSAthenaOperator, but using that is also failing.

Answer (score 0):

Following as well worked for me. I just complicated simple problem with asyncio.

Since I needed S3 URIs for each query at last therefore I went for writing script from scratch. In the current implementation of `AWSAthenaOperator`, one can get the `queryExecutionId` and then do the remaining processing(i.e create another task) for getting S3 URI of CSV result file. This can add some overhead in terms of delay between two tasks(of getting `queryExecutionId` and retrieving S3 URI) along with added resource usuage.

Therefore I went for doing the complete operation in a single operator as follows:-

Code:-

```
import json
import time
import asyncio
import boto3
import logging
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator


def execute_query(client, query, database, output_location):
    response = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=query,
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': database
        },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': output_location
        }
    )

    return response


def run_athena_query(query, database, output_location, region_name, **context):
    BOTO_SESSION = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id = 'YOUR_KEY',
        aws_secret_access_key = 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY')
    client_athena = BOTO_SESSION.client('athena', region_name=region_name)

    query_execution_ids = []
    if message_list:
        for parameter in message_list:
            query_response = execute_query(client_athena, query, database, output_location)
            query_execution_ids.append(query_response['QueryExecutionId'])
    else:
        raise Exception(
            'Error in upstream value recived from kafka consumer. Got message list as - {}, with type {}'
                .format(message_list, type(message_list))
        )


    repetitions = 900
    error_messages = []
    s3_uris = []

    while repetitions > 0 and len(query_execution_ids) > 0:
        repetitions = repetitions - 1
        
        query_response_list = client_athena.batch_get_query_execution(
            QueryExecutionIds=query_execution_ids)['QueryExecutions']
      
        for query_response in query_response_list:
            if 'QueryExecution' in query_response and \
                    'Status' in query_response['QueryExecution'] and \
                    'State' in query_response['QueryExecution']['Status']:
                state = query_response['QueryExecution']['Status']['State']

                if state in ['FAILED', 'CANCELLED']:
                    error_reason = query_response['QueryExecution']['Status']['StateChangeReason']
                    error_message = 'Final state of Athena job is {}, query_execution_id is {}. Error: {}'.format(
                            state, query_execution_id, error_message
                        )
                    error_messages.append(error_message)
                    query_execution_ids.remove(query_response['QueryExecutionId'])
                
                elif state == 'SUCCEEDED':
                    result_location = query_response['QueryExecution']['ResultConfiguration']['OutputLocation']
                    s3_uris.append(result_location)
                    query_execution_ids.remove(query_response['QueryExecutionId'])
                 
                    
        time.sleep(2)
    
    logging.exception(error_messages)
    return s3_uris


DEFAULT_ARGS = {
    'owner': 'ubuntu',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'start_date': datetime(2021, 6, 8),
    'retries': 0,
    'concurrency': 2
}

with DAG('resync_job_dag', default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS, schedule_interval=None) as dag:

    ATHENA_QUERY = PythonOperator(
        task_id='athena_query',
        python_callable=run_athena_query,
        provide_context=True,
        op_kwargs={
            'query': 'SELECT request_timestamp FROM "sampledb"."elb_logs" limit 10;', # query provide in athena tutorial
            'database':'sampledb',
            'output_location':'YOUR_BUCKET',
            'region_name':'YOUR_REGION'
        }
    )

    ATHENA_QUERY
```

However, the approach shared by @Elad is more clean and apt if one wants to get `queryExecutionIds` of all the queries.